# How can I clean this code up? Seperate CSS attempt failed

Tags: javascript, html, css, code-cleanup

I recently started on a new project and I needed to redesign a website but before getting to that I wanted to "clean up" the code. It is just a mess as you can see below.
Now I wanted to move this to a new css file:`<style type="text/css"></style>`and there is more to be transferred to the css file (for example the position, colour and other make-up things).

Now I transferred the css text to a new style.css file and referred to it with:`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">`but after deleting the css code from the html file it did not show any changes. Wel it did show some but not as it was before.

How can I transfer this css code to a seperate file? It works fine as it is now but when I move it to a new file it does not.

Anyway here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html lang="nl">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="Generator" content="Serif WebPlus 11.0.8.033">
<title>Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
a:link {color: #3e550e;}
a:visited {color: #8e9165;}
a:hover {color: #3e550e;}
a:active {color: #3e550e;}
.Standaard-P
        {
        margin:0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; text-align:center; font-weight:400; 
        }
.Standaard-P0
        {
        margin:0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; text-align:left; font-weight:400; 
        }
.Standaard-C
        {
        font-family:"Tahoma", sans-serif; font-size:11.0px; line-height:1.18em; 
        color:#37b0c1; 
        }
.Standaard-C0
        {
        font-family:"GrilledCheese BTN Wide Blk", sans-serif; 
        font-size:20.0px; line-height:1.40em; color:#ad0e0b; 
        }
.Standaard-C1
        {
        font-family:"GrilledCheese BTN Wide Blk", sans-serif; 
        font-size:20.0px; line-height:1.40em; color:#27ffa6; 
        }
.Standaard-C2
        {
        font-family:"GrilledCheese BTN Wide Blk", sans-serif; 
        font-size:20.0px; line-height:1.40em; color:#00ffff; 
        }
.Standaard-C3
        {
        font-family:"GrilledCheese BTN Wide Blk", sans-serif; 
        font-size:29.0px; line-height:1.38em; color:#ad0e0b; 
        }
.Standaard-C4
        {
        font-family:"GrilledCheese BTN Wide Blk", sans-serif; 
        font-size:17.0px; line-height:1.41em; color:#ad0e0b; 
        }
.Standaard-C5
        {
        font-family:"Tahoma", sans-serif; font-weight:700; font-size:16.0px; 
        line-height:1.19em; 
        }
.Standaard-C6
        {
        font-family:"Tahoma", sans-serif; font-size:16.0px; line-height:1.19em; 
        }
.Hyperlink-C
        {
        font-family:"GrilledCheese BTN Wide Blk", sans-serif; 
        font-size:20.0px; line-height:1.40em; color:#4cfff7; 
        text-decoration: underline; 
        }
.Hyperlink-C0
        {
        font-family:"GrilledCheese BTN Wide Blk", sans-serif; 
        font-size:20.0px; line-height:1.40em; color:#53ff19; 
        text-decoration: underline; 
        }
.Hyperlink-C1
        {
        font-family:"GrilledCheese BTN Wide Blk", sans-serif; 
        font-size:16.0px; line-height:1.38em; color:#4cfff7; 
        text-decoration: underline; 
        }
-->
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
var blankSrc = "wpscripts/blank.gif";
--></script>
<script src="wpscripts/jspngfix.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="wpscripts/jsDetectBrowser.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="wpscripts/jsMenus.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var wp_menubar0 = new wp_menus();
wp_menubar0.m_bkgndcolor = '#edad0e';
wp_menubar0.m_bkgndcolorhl = '#37b0c1';
wp_menubar0.m_textcolor = '#800000';
wp_menubar0.m_textcolorhl = '#000080';
wp_menubar0.m_bordercolor = '#000080';
wp_menubar0.m_bordersize = 1;
wp_menubar0.m_fontsize = 13;
wp_menubar0.m_fontbold = true;
wp_menubar0.m_imagearrow = 'wpimages/wp68960b01.gif';
wp_menubar0.m_imagearrowhl = 'wpimages/wpb841bcb5.gif';
wp_menubar0.m_txtalign = 'center';
wp_menubar0.m_fontfamily = 'Tahoma,serif';
wp_menubar0.m_filterOpacity = 100;
wp_menubar0.m_mozOpacity = 1.000000;
wp_menubar0.m_delay = 500;
wp_menubar0.m_itemlines = true;
wp_menubar0.m_width = 0;
wp_menubar0.m_acStack.type = 1;
wp_menubar0.m_acStack.m_showbelow = true;
wp_menubar0.m_acStack.m_showright = true;
wp_menubar0.m_acStack.gap = 1;
wp_menubar0.m_acStack.bordergap = 1;
wp_menubar0.m_acStack.m_firstpopup = 1;
wp_menubar0.BeginMenu('wp_menubar0_P2');
wp_menubar0.AddLink('wp_menubar0_P2_I0','Werkboek','werkboek.html',null,'_self');
wp_menubar0.AddLink('wp_menubar0_P2_I1','Bestellen werkboek','werkboek_bestellen.html',null,'_self');
wp_menubar0.AddLink('wp_menubar0_P2_I2','Bestelformulier Werkboek / Rebozo','werkboek_bestelformulier.html',null,'_self');
wp_menubar0.AddLink('wp_menubar0_P2_I3','Voorzijde Rebozowerkboek','werkboek_rebozo_voorzijde.html',null,'_self');
wp_menubar0.AddLink('wp_menubar0_P2_I4','Achterzijde Rebozowerkboek','werkboek_rebozo_achterzijde',null,'_self');
wp_menubar0.AddLink('wp_menubar0_P2_I5','Foto&#39;s boekpresentatie ','pagina71aaaaaaaa.html',null,'_self');
wp_menubar0.EndMenu();
wp_menubar0.BeginMenu('wp_menubar0_P4');
wp_menubar0.AddLink('wp_menubar0_P4_I0','Workshop','pagina71aaaaaaaaaaaa.html',null,'_self');
wp_menubar0.AddLink('wp_menubar0_P4_I1','Programma workshop','pagina71.html',null,'_self');
wp_menubar0.AddLink('wp_menubar0_P4_I2','Foto impressie workshop','pagina71aaaaa.html',null,'_self');
wp_menubar0.AddLink('wp_menubar0_P4_I3','Persberichten','pagina71aaaaaaaaa.html','wp_menubar0_P4_P4','_self');
wp_menubar0.AddLink('wp_menubar0_P4_I4','Aanmelding workshop','pagina71aa.html',null,'_self');
wp_menubar0.EndMenu();
wp_menubar0.BeginMenu('wp_menubar0_P4_P4');
wp_menubar0.AddLink('wp_menubar0_P4_P4_I0','Weleda','pagina71aaaaaaaaaa.html',null,'_self');
wp_menubar0.AddLink('wp_menubar0_P4_P4_I1','Educare','pagina71aaaaaaaaaaa.html',null,'_self');
wp_menubar0.EndMenu();
wp_menubar0.BeginMenu('wp_menubar0_P9');
wp_menubar0.AddLink('wp_menubar0_P9_I0','Workbook','pagina2aaaaa.html',null,'_self');
wp_menubar0.AddLink('wp_menubar0_P9_I1','Order Workbook','pagina2aaaaaa.html',null,'_self');
wp_menubar0.AddLink('wp_menubar0_P9_I2','Order-form workbook','pagina71aaaaaaaaaaaaa.html',null,'_self');
wp_menubar0.AddLink('wp_menubar0_P9_I3','Front cover','pagina2aaaaaaa.html',null,'_self');
wp_menubar0.AddLink('wp_menubar0_P9_I4','Back cover','pagina2aaaaaaaa.html',null,'_self');
wp_menubar0.AddLink('wp_menubar0_P9_I5','About the authors','pagina71aaa.html',null,'_self');
wp_menubar0.EndMenu();
//-->
</script>
</head>

<body text="#000000" style="background: #424242; position:relative; height:80% text-align:center;">
<div style="background: #0c6684; position:relative;width:80%;height:80%;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
<div style="position:absolute; left:39px; top:34px; width:683px; height:207px;">
    <img src="wpimages/wp6a71e827.png" width="100%" height="100%" border="0" id="art_1" name="art_1" title="" alt="www.Rebozo.nl" onload="OnLoadPngFix()"></div>
<div style="position:absolute; left:40px; top:833px; width:680px; height:7px;">
    <img src="wpimages/wp9cc26935.png" width="680" height="7" border="0" id="qs_13" name="qs_13" title="" alt="" onload="OnLoadPngFix()"></div>
<div id="txt_11" style="position:absolute; left:453px; top:845px; width:291px; height:15px;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box; overflow:hidden;">
<P class="Standaard-P"><span class="Standaard-C">© webdesign: M. van Druten voor www.rebozo.nl</span></P>
</div>
<div style="text-align:left; position:absolute; left:37px; top:260px;">
    <a href="index.html" target="_self"><img alt="Home." title="" id="wp_menubar0_0" src="wpimages/wpcd722a5f.png" style="border:0;width:211px;height:33px" onmouseover="wp_MenuItemOver('wp_menubar0_0',wp_menubar0,null);" onmouseout="wp_MenuItemOut('wp_menubar0_0',wp_menubar0);" onload="OnLoadPngFix();"></a><br>
    <a href="pagina2.html" target="_self"><img alt="Werkboek." title="" id="wp_menubar0_1" src="wpimages/wp38c91c8c.png" style="border:0;width:211px;height:33px" onmouseover="wp_MenuItemOver('wp_menubar0_1',wp_menubar0,'wp_menubar0_P2');" onmouseout="wp_MenuItemOut('wp_menubar0_1',wp_menubar0);" onload="OnLoadPngFix();"></a><br>
    <a href="pagina2aaaaaaaaa.html" target="_self"><img alt="Rebozo bestellen." title="" id="wp_menubar0_2" src="wpimages/wpaf7cea79.png" style="border:0;width:211px;height:33px" onmouseover="wp_MenuItemOver('wp_menubar0_2',wp_menubar0,null);" onmouseout="wp_MenuItemOut('wp_menubar0_2',wp_menubar0);" onload="OnLoadPngFix();"></a><br>
    <a href="pagina71a.html" target="_self"><img alt="Workshop." title="" id="wp_menubar0_3" src="wpimages/wp985c7d1f.png" style="border:0;width:211px;height:33px" onmouseover="wp_MenuItemOver('wp_menubar0_3',wp_menubar0,'wp_menubar0_P4');" onmouseout="wp_MenuItemOut('wp_menubar0_3',wp_menubar0);" onload="OnLoadPngFix();"></a><br>
    <a href="pagina71aaaaaaaaaaaaaa.html" target="_self"><img alt="Over ons." title="" id="wp_menubar0_4" src="wpimages/wp72392f04.png" style="border:0;width:211px;height:33px" onmouseover="wp_MenuItemOver('wp_menubar0_4',wp_menubar0,null);" onmouseout="wp_MenuItemOut('wp_menubar0_4',wp_menubar0);" onload="OnLoadPngFix();"></a><br>
    <a href="pagina71aaaaaa.html" target="_self"><img alt="Contact." title="" id="wp_menubar0_5" src="wpimages/wp03f6932f.png" style="border:0;width:211px;height:33px" onmouseover="wp_MenuItemOver('wp_menubar0_5',wp_menubar0,null);" onmouseout="wp_MenuItemOut('wp_menubar0_5',wp_menubar0);" onload="OnLoadPngFix();"></a><br>
    <a href="pagina71aaaaaaa.html" target="_self"><img alt="Links." title="" id="wp_menubar0_6" src="wpimages/wpc00d0795.png" style="border:0;width:211px;height:33px" onmouseover="wp_MenuItemOver('wp_menubar0_6',wp_menubar0,null);" onmouseout="wp_MenuItemOut('wp_menubar0_6',wp_menubar0);" onload="OnLoadPngFix();"></a><br>
    <a href="indexa.html" target="_self"><img alt="English version." title="" id="wp_menubar0_7" src="wpimages/wpb3eff106.png" style="border:0;width:211px;height:33px" onmouseover="wp_MenuItemOver('wp_menubar0_7',wp_menubar0,'wp_menubar0_P9');" onmouseout="wp_MenuItemOut('wp_menubar0_7',wp_menubar0);" onload="OnLoadPngFix();"></a><br>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    wp_menubar0.InitElement('wp_menubar0_0','wpimages/wpcd722a5f.png','wpimages/wpcd722a5f.png');
    wp_menubar0.InitElement('wp_menubar0_1','wpimages/wp38c91c8c.png','wpimages/wp38c91c8c.png');
    wp_menubar0.InitElement('wp_menubar0_2','wpimages/wpaf7cea79.png','wpimages/wpaf7cea79.png');
    wp_menubar0.InitElement('wp_menubar0_3','wpimages/wp985c7d1f.png','wpimages/wp985c7d1f.png');
    wp_menubar0.InitElement('wp_menubar0_4','wpimages/wp72392f04.png','wpimages/wp72392f04.png');
    wp_menubar0.InitElement('wp_menubar0_5','wpimages/wp03f6932f.png','wpimages/wp03f6932f.png');
    wp_menubar0.InitElement('wp_menubar0_6','wpimages/wpc00d0795.png','wpimages/wpc00d0795.png');
    wp_menubar0.InitElement('wp_menubar0_7','wpimages/wpb3eff106.png','wpimages/wpb3eff106.png');
    //-->
    </script>
</div>
<div style="position:absolute; left:307px; top:696px; width:164px; height:104px;">
    <map id="map0" name="map0">
        <area shape="rect" coords="17,1,165,92" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hcr3EUEfA6M" alt="">
    </map>
    <img src="wpimages/wp3c8657e6_02.jpg" width="164" height="104" border="0" id="pic_85" name="pic_85" title="" alt="" usemap="#map0"></div>
<div style="position:absolute; left:261px; top:260px; width:461px; height:400px;">
    <img src="wpimages/wp399788b7.png" width="461" height="400" border="0" id="qs_14" name="qs_14" title="" alt="" onload="OnLoadPngFix()"></div>
<div style="position:absolute; left:57px; top:712px; width:180px; height:19px;">
    <img src="wpimages/wpb26a6a80.png" width="180" height="19" border="0" id="art_11" name="art_11" title="" alt="" onload="OnLoadPngFix()"></div>
<div style="position:absolute; left:479px; top:669px; width:243px; height:121px;">
    <img src="wpimages/wp70844bb8.png" width="243" height="121" border="0" id="qs_84" name="qs_84" title="" alt="" onload="OnLoadPngFix()"></div>
<div id="txt_60" style="position:absolute; left:443px; top:683px; width:307px; height:93px;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box; overflow:hidden;">
<P class="Standaard-P"><span class="Standaard-C0">Bestel</span><span class="Standaard-C1"> </span><span class="Standaard-C2"><a href="pagina2a.html" style="color:#00ffff;">hier</a></span><span class="Standaard-C1"> </span><span class="Standaard-C0">het </span></P>
<P class="Standaard-P"><span class="Standaard-C3">Werkboek</span></P>
<P class="Standaard-P"><span class="Standaard-C4">Rebozotechniek</span></P>
</div>
<div style="position:absolute; left:259px; top:259px; width:465px; height:401px;">
    <img src="wpimages/wp5f208f41.png" width="465" height="401" border="0" id="qs_20" name="qs_20" title="" alt="" onload="OnLoadPngFix()"></div>
<div style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:559px; width:320px; height:311px;">
    <map id="map1" name="map1">
        <area shape="rect" coords="24,0,321,308" href="pagina2.html" alt="">
    </map>
    <img src="wpimages/wpb6d9d1ba.png" width="320" height="311" border="0" id="drie_1" name="drie_1" title="" alt="Werkboek" onload="OnLoadPngFix()" usemap="#map1"></div>
<div id="txt_65" style="position:absolute; left:293px; top:283px; width:407px; height:355px;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box; overflow:hidden;">
<P class="Standaard-P0"><span class="Standaard-C5">Welkom op www.Rebozo.nl, </span></P>
<P class="Standaard-P0"><span class="Standaard-C6">de site die informeert over de massagetechniek met de traditionele draagdoek: de
    Rebozo.</span></P>
<P class="Standaard-P0"><span class="Standaard-C6">&nbsp;</span></P>
<P class="Standaard-P0"><span class="Standaard-C6">Deze massagetechniek werd oorspronkelijk door verloskundigen uit Midden-Amerika toegepast
    bij de voorbereiding van zwangeren op de bevalling.</span></P>
<P class="Standaard-P0"><span class="Standaard-C6">Mede door de opkomst van de Doula is deze techniek ook in het Westen geintroduceerd.
    </span></P>
<P class="Standaard-P0"><span class="Standaard-C6">Met de groeiende bekendheid van de Doula, neemt ook de toepassing van de Rebozo toe.
    </span></P>
<P class="Standaard-P0"><span class="Standaard-C6">&nbsp;</span></P>
<P class="Standaard-P0"><span class="Standaard-C6">Ons doel is deze eenvoudige, maar zeer doeltreffende techniek, een bredere bekendheid
    te geven. </span></P>
<P class="Standaard-P0"><span class="Standaard-C6">Het uitgangspunt is de traditionele toepassing bij zwangeren, barenden en kraamvrouwen.
    Daarnaast zijn er meer mogelijkheden de Rebozo toe te passen bij zeer uiteenlopende
    doelgroepen.</span></P>
</div>
<div style="position:absolute; left:236px; top:797px; width:448px; height:28px;">
    <div class="Standaard-P0">
        <span class="Hyperlink-C">Also </span><span class="Hyperlink-C0">English version</span><span class="Hyperlink-C"> available!</span></div>
</div>
<div style="position:absolute; left:671px; top:796px; width:52px; height:30px;">
    <a href="indexa.html"><img src="wpimages/wp410e0b32.gif" width="52" height="30" border="0" id="agif1" name="agif1" title="" alt="English version"></a></div>
<div style="position:absolute; left:322px; top:672px; width:169px; height:22px;">
    <div class="Standaard-P0">
        <span class="Hyperlink-C1"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hcr3EUEfA6M" style="color:#4cfff7;text-decoration:none;">TV opnames!</a></span></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: most likely a problem with the path to the css file. the way u link it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Absolute vs relative URLs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls)

Comment: Try putting the css file in the same directory as the webpage and changing the href in the link tag to just "style.css" If it works then, you have path based problem. You didn't have the correct path relative to the html page in the link tag.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you have a problem with your relative/absolute path , and how you link your CSS.

Please read more about [relative/absolute patching here](http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/a/aa040502a.htm)  [or here](http://jeffreybarke.net/2013/06/paths-and-urls-relative-and-absolute/)

Easiest way to test is to put your entire path in your link

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yourwebsite/path-to-css/css/style.css">
```

Comment: But it seems to get some styles working and it is clearly different when I delete the whole css. But when I input the css in the same page (by using <style type="text/css"></style>) then it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

On the `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path to css.css">` line change it to the appropriate location for your css file, and then just paste all your css in the style.css file.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
    <html lang="nl">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="Generator" content="Serif WebPlus 11.0.8.033">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path to css.css"> /* path to your css file */
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
    var blankSrc = "wpscripts/blank.gif";
    --></script>
    <script src="wpscripts/jspngfix.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="wpscripts/jsDetectBrowser.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="wpscripts/jsMenus.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    var wp_menubar0 = new wp_menus();
    wp_menubar0.m_bkgndcolor = '#edad0e';
    wp_menubar0.m_bkgndcolorhl = '#37b0c1';
    wp_menubar0.m_textcolor = '#800000';
    wp_menubar0.m_textcolorhl = '#000080';
    wp_menubar0.m_bordercolor = '#000080';
    wp_menubar0.m_bordersize = 1;
    wp_menubar0.m_fontsize = 13;
    wp_menubar0.m_fontbold = true;
    wp_menubar0.m_imagearrow = 'wpimages/wp68960b01.gif';
    wp_menubar0.m_imagearrowhl = 'wpimages/wpb841bcb5.gif';
    wp_menubar0.m_txtalign = 'center';
    wp_menubar0.m_fontfamily = 'Tahoma,serif';
    wp_menubar0.m_filterOpacity = 100;
    wp_menubar0.m_mozOpacity = 1.000000;
    wp_menubar0.m_delay = 500;
    wp_menubar0.m_itemlines = true;
    wp_menubar0.m_width = 0;
    wp_menubar0.m_acStack.type = 1;
    wp_menubar0.m_acStack.m_showbelow = true;
    wp_menubar0.m_acStack.m_showright = true;
    wp_menubar0.m_acStack.gap = 1;
    wp_menubar0.m_acStack.bordergap = 1;
    wp_menubar0.m_acStack.m_firstpopup = 1;
    wp_menubar0.BeginMenu('wp_menubar0_P2');
    wp_menubar0.AddLink('wp_menubar0_P2_I0','Werkboek','werkboek.html',null,'_self');
    wp_menubar0.AddLink('wp_menubar0_P2_I1','Bestellen werkboek','werkboek_bestellen.html',null,'_self');
    wp_menubar0.AddLink('wp_menubar0_P2_I2','Bestelformulier Werkboek / Rebozo','werkboek_bestelformulier.html',null,'_self');
    wp_menubar0.AddLink('wp_menubar0_P2_I3','Voorzijde Rebozowerkboek','werkboek_rebozo_voorzijde.html',null,'_self');
    wp_menubar0.AddLink('wp_menubar0_P2_I4','Achterzijde Rebozowerkboek','werkboek_rebozo_achterzijde',null,'_self');
    wp_menubar0.AddLink('wp_menubar0_P2_I5','Foto&#39;s boekpresentatie ','pagina71aaaaaaaa.html',null,'_self');
    wp_menubar0.EndMenu();
    wp_menubar0.BeginMenu('wp_menubar0_P4');
    wp_menubar0.AddLink('wp_menubar0_P4_I0','Workshop','pagina71aaaaaaaaaaaa.html',null,'_self');
    wp_menubar0.AddLink('wp_menubar0_P4_I1','Programma workshop','pagina71.html',null,'_self');
    wp_menubar0.AddLink('wp_menubar0_P4_I2','Foto impressie workshop','pagina71aaaaa.html',null,'_self');
    wp_menubar0.AddLink('wp_menubar0_P4_I3','Persberichten','pagina71aaaaaaaaa.html','wp_menubar0_P4_P4','_self');
    wp_menubar0.AddLink('wp_menubar0_P4_I4','Aanmelding workshop','pagina71aa.html',null,'_self');
    wp_menubar0.EndMenu();
    wp_menubar0.BeginMenu('wp_menubar0_P4_P4');
    wp_menubar0.AddLink('wp_menubar0_P4_P4_I0','Weleda','pagina71aaaaaaaaaa.html',null,'_self');
    wp_menubar0.AddLink('wp_menubar0_P4_P4_I1','Educare','pagina71aaaaaaaaaaa.html',null,'_self');
    wp_menubar0.EndMenu();
    wp_menubar0.BeginMenu('wp_menubar0_P9');
    wp_menubar0.AddLink('wp_menubar0_P9_I0','Workbook','pagina2aaaaa.html',null,'_self');
    wp_menubar0.AddLink('wp_menubar0_P9_I1','Order Workbook','pagina2aaaaaa.html',null,'_self');
    wp_menubar0.AddLink('wp_menubar0_P9_I2','Order-form workbook','pagina71aaaaaaaaaaaaa.html',null,'_self');
    wp_menubar0.AddLink('wp_menubar0_P9_I3','Front cover','pagina2aaaaaaa.html',null,'_self');
    wp_menubar0.AddLink('wp_menubar0_P9_I4','Back cover','pagina2aaaaaaaa.html',null,'_self');
    wp_menubar0.AddLink('wp_menubar0_P9_I5','About the authors','pagina71aaa.html',null,'_self');
    wp_menubar0.EndMenu();
    //-->
    </script>
    </head>

    <body text="#000000" style="background: #424242; position:relative; height:80% text-align:center;">
    <div style="background: #0c6684; position:relative;width:80%;height:80%;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
    <div style="position:absolute; left:39px; top:34px; width:683px; height:207px;">
        <img src="wpimages/wp6a71e827.png" width="100%" height="100%" border="0" id="art_1" name="art_1" title="" alt="www.Rebozo.nl" onload="OnLoadPngFix()"></div>
    <div style="position:absolute; left:40px; top:833px; width:680px; height:7px;">
        <img src="wpimages/wp9cc26935.png" width="680" height="7" border="0" id="qs_13" name="qs_13" title="" alt="" onload="OnLoadPngFix()"></div>
    <div id="txt_11" style="position:absolute; left:453px; top:845px; width:291px; height:15px;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box; overflow:hidden;">
    <P class="Standaard-P"><span class="Standaard-C">© webdesign: M. van Druten voor www.rebozo.nl</span></P>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align:left; position:absolute; left:37px; top:260px;">
        <a href="index.html" target="_self"><img alt="Home." title="" id="wp_menubar0_0" src="wpimages/wpcd722a5f.png" style="border:0;width:211px;height:33px" onmouseover="wp_MenuItemOver('wp_menubar0_0',wp_menubar0,null);" onmouseout="wp_MenuItemOut('wp_menubar0_0',wp_menubar0);" onload="OnLoadPngFix();"></a><br>
        <a href="pagina2.html" target="_self"><img alt="Werkboek." title="" id="wp_menubar0_1" src="wpimages/wp38c91c8c.png" style="border:0;width:211px;height:33px" onmouseover="wp_MenuItemOver('wp_menubar0_1',wp_menubar0,'wp_menubar0_P2');" onmouseout="wp_MenuItemOut('wp_menubar0_1',wp_menubar0);" onload="OnLoadPngFix();"></a><br>
        <a href="pagina2aaaaaaaaa.html" target="_self"><img alt="Rebozo bestellen." title="" id="wp_menubar0_2" src="wpimages/wpaf7cea79.png" style="border:0;width:211px;height:33px" onmouseover="wp_MenuItemOver('wp_menubar0_2',wp_menubar0,null);" onmouseout="wp_MenuItemOut('wp_menubar0_2',wp_menubar0);" onload="OnLoadPngFix();"></a><br>
        <a href="pagina71a.html" target="_self"><img alt="Workshop." title="" id="wp_menubar0_3" src="wpimages/wp985c7d1f.png" style="border:0;width:211px;height:33px" onmouseover="wp_MenuItemOver('wp_menubar0_3',wp_menubar0,'wp_menubar0_P4');" onmouseout="wp_MenuItemOut('wp_menubar0_3',wp_menubar0);" onload="OnLoadPngFix();"></a><br>
        <a href="pagina71aaaaaaaaaaaaaa.html" target="_self"><img alt="Over ons." title="" id="wp_menubar0_4" src="wpimages/wp72392f04.png" style="border:0;width:211px;height:33px" onmouseover="wp_MenuItemOver('wp_menubar0_4',wp_menubar0,null);" onmouseout="wp_MenuItemOut('wp_menubar0_4',wp_menubar0);" onload="OnLoadPngFix();"></a><br>
        <a href="pagina71aaaaaa.html" target="_self"><img alt="Contact." title="" id="wp_menubar0_5" src="wpimages/wp03f6932f.png" style="border:0;width:211px;height:33px" onmouseover="wp_MenuItemOver('wp_menubar0_5',wp_menubar0,null);" onmouseout="wp_MenuItemOut('wp_menubar0_5',wp_menubar0);" onload="OnLoadPngFix();"></a><br>
        <a href="pagina71aaaaaaa.html" target="_self"><img alt="Links." title="" id="wp_menubar0_6" src="wpimages/wpc00d0795.png" style="border:0;width:211px;height:33px" onmouseover="wp_MenuItemOver('wp_menubar0_6',wp_menubar0,null);" onmouseout="wp_MenuItemOut('wp_menubar0_6',wp_menubar0);" onload="OnLoadPngFix();"></a><br>
        <a href="indexa.html" target="_self"><img alt="English version." title="" id="wp_menubar0_7" src="wpimages/wpb3eff106.png" style="border:0;width:211px;height:33px" onmouseover="wp_MenuItemOver('wp_menubar0_7',wp_menubar0,'wp_menubar0_P9');" onmouseout="wp_MenuItemOut('wp_menubar0_7',wp_menubar0);" onload="OnLoadPngFix();"></a><br>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        wp_menubar0.InitElement('wp_menubar0_0','wpimages/wpcd722a5f.png','wpimages/wpcd722a5f.png');
        wp_menubar0.InitElement('wp_menubar0_1','wpimages/wp38c91c8c.png','wpimages/wp38c91c8c.png');
        wp_menubar0.InitElement('wp_menubar0_2','wpimages/wpaf7cea79.png','wpimages/wpaf7cea79.png');
        wp_menubar0.InitElement('wp_menubar0_3','wpimages/wp985c7d1f.png','wpimages/wp985c7d1f.png');
        wp_menubar0.InitElement('wp_menubar0_4','wpimages/wp72392f04.png','wpimages/wp72392f04.png');
        wp_menubar0.InitElement('wp_menubar0_5','wpimages/wp03f6932f.png','wpimages/wp03f6932f.png');
        wp_menubar0.InitElement('wp_menubar0_6','wpimages/wpc00d0795.png','wpimages/wpc00d0795.png');
        wp_menubar0.InitElement('wp_menubar0_7','wpimages/wpb3eff106.png','wpimages/wpb3eff106.png');
        //-->
        </script>
    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute; left:307px; top:696px; width:164px; height:104px;">
        <map id="map0" name="map0">
            <area shape="rect" coords="17,1,165,92" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hcr3EUEfA6M" alt="">
        </map>
        <img src="wpimages/wp3c8657e6_02.jpg" width="164" height="104" border="0" id="pic_85" name="pic_85" title="" alt="" usemap="#map0"></div>
    <div style="position:absolute; left:261px; top:260px; width:461px; height:400px;">
        <img src="wpimages/wp399788b7.png" width="461" height="400" border="0" id="qs_14" name="qs_14" title="" alt="" onload="OnLoadPngFix()"></div>
    <div style="position:absolute; left:57px; top:712px; width:180px; height:19px;">
        <img src="wpimages/wpb26a6a80.png" width="180" height="19" border="0" id="art_11" name="art_11" title="" alt="" onload="OnLoadPngFix()"></div>
    <div style="position:absolute; left:479px; top:669px; width:243px; height:121px;">
        <img src="wpimages/wp70844bb8.png" width="243" height="121" border="0" id="qs_84" name="qs_84" title="" alt="" onload="OnLoadPngFix()"></div>
    <div id="txt_60" style="position:absolute; left:443px; top:683px; width:307px; height:93px;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box; overflow:hidden;">
    <P class="Standaard-P"><span class="Standaard-C0">Bestel</span><span class="Standaard-C1"> </span><span class="Standaard-C2"><a href="pagina2a.html" style="color:#00ffff;">hier</a></span><span class="Standaard-C1"> </span><span class="Standaard-C0">het </span></P>
    <P class="Standaard-P"><span class="Standaard-C3">Werkboek</span></P>
    <P class="Standaard-P"><span class="Standaard-C4">Rebozotechniek</span></P>
    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute; left:259px; top:259px; width:465px; height:401px;">
        <img src="wpimages/wp5f208f41.png" width="465" height="401" border="0" id="qs_20" name="qs_20" title="" alt="" onload="OnLoadPngFix()"></div>
    <div style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:559px; width:320px; height:311px;">
        <map id="map1" name="map1">
            <area shape="rect" coords="24,0,321,308" href="pagina2.html" alt="">
        </map>
        <img src="wpimages/wpb6d9d1ba.png" width="320" height="311" border="0" id="drie_1" name="drie_1" title="" alt="Werkboek" onload="OnLoadPngFix()" usemap="#map1"></div>
    <div id="txt_65" style="position:absolute; left:293px; top:283px; width:407px; height:355px;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box; overflow:hidden;">
    <P class="Standaard-P0"><span class="Standaard-C5">Welkom op www.Rebozo.nl, </span></P>
    <P class="Standaard-P0"><span class="Standaard-C6">de site die informeert over de massagetechniek met de traditionele draagdoek: de
        Rebozo.</span></P>
    <P class="Standaard-P0"><span class="Standaard-C6">&nbsp;</span></P>
    <P class="Standaard-P0"><span class="Standaard-C6">Deze massagetechniek werd oorspronkelijk door verloskundigen uit Midden-Amerika toegepast
        bij de voorbereiding van zwangeren op de bevalling.</span></P>
    <P class="Standaard-P0"><span class="Standaard-C6">Mede door de opkomst van de Doula is deze techniek ook in het Westen geintroduceerd.
        </span></P>
    <P class="Standaard-P0"><span class="Standaard-C6">Met de groeiende bekendheid van de Doula, neemt ook de toepassing van de Rebozo toe.
        </span></P>
    <P class="Standaard-P0"><span class="Standaard-C6">&nbsp;</span></P>
    <P class="Standaard-P0"><span class="Standaard-C6">Ons doel is deze eenvoudige, maar zeer doeltreffende techniek, een bredere bekendheid
        te geven. </span></P>
    <P class="Standaard-P0"><span class="Standaard-C6">Het uitgangspunt is de traditionele toepassing bij zwangeren, barenden en kraamvrouwen.
        Daarnaast zijn er meer mogelijkheden de Rebozo toe te passen bij zeer uiteenlopende
        doelgroepen.</span></P>
    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute; left:236px; top:797px; width:448px; height:28px;">
        <div class="Standaard-P0">
            <span class="Hyperlink-C">Also </span><span class="Hyperlink-C0">English version</span><span class="Hyperlink-C"> available!</span></div>
    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute; left:671px; top:796px; width:52px; height:30px;">
        <a href="indexa.html"><img src="wpimages/wp410e0b32.gif" width="52" height="30" border="0" id="agif1" name="agif1" title="" alt="English version"></a></div>
    <div style="position:absolute; left:322px; top:672px; width:169px; height:22px;">
        <div class="Standaard-P0">
            <span class="Hyperlink-C1"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hcr3EUEfA6M" style="color:#4cfff7;text-decoration:none;">TV opnames!</a></span></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```